# Creating "brick breaker" game and upon starting a level I get a sound effect before ball even launches

Tags: c#, audio, unity-game-engine

I'm still very much a newbie with understanding scripting and the vocab associated with it. I'm following a course online right now and I'm trying to be brave and venture out from the videos and make my own script work using different sounds on different bricks.

I want the ball to make a certain sound ("bip") when it bounces off of the paddle. However, when I start a level, before the ball is even launched, I get the "bip" sound. In the tutorial video he puts the sound associated with the ball and so doesn't have this issue after changing some of his code. Mine still persists. I already have a script for my ball, brick, and paddle. In my Ball script I have a `public bool hasStarted = false;` before my Start function. And I don't want to make `hasStarted` a private bool in each script. I want to just be able to call it from another script, and I don't want to make it static either so that I can support having multiple balls in one level.

So question number one: are all `bool` considered static by default?

Question two: Here's what I have for my paddle script. What can I do to prevent the starting "bip" when starting a level?

```
public class Paddle : MonoBehaviour {

//private bool hasStarted = false;

//Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

//Update is called once per frame
void Update(){
    Vector3 paddlePos = new Vector3 (0.5f, this.transform.position.y, 0f); //initial set position of the paddle on screen

    float mousePosInBlocks = Input.mousePosition.x / Screen.width * 16; //creates a variable called mousePosInBlocks to track
                                                                        //the position of the mouse X vector in game units

    paddlePos.x = Mathf.Clamp(mousePosInBlocks, 0.5f, 15.5f);   //setting the x vector of paddlePos e.g. the left/right function
                                                                //of the paddle to be the same as the mouse position on screen

    this.transform.position = paddlePos;    //the Object with the attached script (Paddle) is fed the updated
                                            //position info from the preceding 3 lines of code
}

void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col){
    // I need to do something with the code here to prevent a "bip" from starting before the ball is even launched
    // Find the game object which is called "Ball".
    GameObject ballObject = GameObject.Find("Ball");
    // Get the instance of the script, which is attached to the ball
    Ball ball = ballObject.GetComponent<Ball>();
    // Check if the ball has started
    if (ball.hasStarted) {
        audio.Play();
    }
}
```

}

Feel free, too, to correct me on my notes. I'm trying to take notes as I write code so that I understand it when I come back to it later.

EDIT: [here](http://pastebin.com/53kZKi3U) is a pastebin screen with both the paddle and ball scripts on them (thanks Joonas).

Comment: On your Audio Source component, is Play On Awake ticked?

Comment: First, bool is type, it's not static unless you declare it static. Second, on your code sample you are calling hasStarted public field on Ball object, but we cannot see the relevant code for the Ball.

Comment: Joonas, [here](http://pastebin.com/53kZKi3U) is the scripts for both the ball and the paddle in one pastebin screen.

Chris, Play On Awake is unchecked. I made sure of that in the first step of trying to figure this out. I wish that's all it was.